# How can I start use utf8mb4 instead of utf8?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, utf-8

I tried to do https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
but after my query

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

messaged this values:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | latin1             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

And when I try to save strings with like this "" symbols it message to me `Incorrect string value: '\xF0`

I read a lot about it and try to switch my columns, table and database in which I store this data from utf8 to utf8mb4.

I set this values in `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
skip-character-set-client-handshake
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

I test mysqld

```
ps -ax | grep mysqld
 1409 ?        Ssl    0:32 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 9299 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysqld
```

and don't sure, but mysqld must contain path to my config file  `/etc/my.cnf` and it missing.

Thanks a lot for any help, I will not ask if not try all that I know and can google myself.

**Small update:**

After I select my database `use booster` I found that there are more variables with `uf8mb4`

that logs about mysql variables I show for all databases, after I did use booster (my database) I found what have more vars with utf8mb4:

`+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | latin1             |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+--------------------------+--------------------+`

Comment: Please read Konstantin Rozinov [comment on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php#121647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the PHP *client* that you are using utf8mb4, not utf8.

- If using mysqli, do `$mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8mb4');`
- If using PDO do somethin like `$db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', $user, $pwd);`
- Alternatively, execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` 
  Any of these will say that the bytes in the client are UTF-8 encoded. Conversion, if necessary, will occur between the client and the database if the column definition is something other than utf8mb4.

Comment: Thanks, I`m using the both, PHP and NodeJS, so will try set names first.

Comment: I found that there are much more variables with utf8mb4 after ```use booster ``` (the database with which I`m working)

Comment: So as I see - I just need to update from latin1 to utf8mb4 too (or utf8) - I saw the bash code which replaces it by doing database dump and import back with the replaced character.

Comment: `init_connect` is not executed when you connect as `root` or other `SUPER` users.

Comment: Yes thanks I create a new non-root user with insert, update, delete permissions and it works for it
But I try insert in PMA and it works too, as I know PMA use root user and it works well

Comment: but my app is a combination of the PHP & NodeJS Apps - my next task is to  fix inserting for node mysql module because it fails anyway)